# R-console Output is not showing even when input is correct

Tags: r

i upgraded to R-version 3.5.3 and R-studio 1.1.463 then i don't see my output on my R-console anymore, please help me with suggestions to solve this problem.

i have tried by r-installing R-studio

i want to be seeing my output on my console in R-studio

attached herein is my data, am using precintcon package in R to do analysis on my data.

Comment: Please add some details highlighting what code you ran, what you got and what you expect to get. Perhaps(in this case) a screenshot?

Comment: as.monthly(data)

Comment: i was actually proceeding to calculate Rainfall Anomaly Index( RAI) >rai(as.monthly(data),granularity"m"), i did same thing two days ago and i saw all my output on the console, including trend test, i only upgraded both R and R-studio and i could not see my output anymore on the R-console

Comment: It's hard to know. I have the same settings and have no issues. Could you share some of your code and data? Edit and add further details **to the question.**